# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file which has more than 100k records and in that record one column has values which are comma separated and I want to sort that comma separated values.

Sample data:

```
"PT3QB789TSUIDF371261","THE TORONTO,DOMINION BANK","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA","XVCCCCCCCCCCYYUUUUU"
"11111111111111111111","ABC,XYZ,QWE","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","POU,ABC,MAS,CA.QC.OSC,CA.ON.OSC","XVRRRRRRRRTTTTTTTTTTTTT"
"22222222222222222222","BHC,NBC,MKY","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","BVC,AZX,CA.SK.FCAA,CA.NL.DSS","QQQQQQQQQRRCGHDKLKSLS"
```

As you can see there is column 2 and column 4 is having comma separated values but I want to sort only column 4 values.
So my output should look like as below :

```
"PT3QB789TSUIDF371261","THE TORONTO,DOMINION BANK","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","AAAA,ASIC*,CA.ON.OSC,MAS","XVCCCCCCCCCCYYUUUUU"
"11111111111111111111","ABC,XYZ,QWE","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","ABC,CA.ON.OSC,CA.QC.OSC,MAS,POU","XVRRRRRRRRTTTTTTTTTTTTT"
"22222222222222222222","BHC,NBC,MKY","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","AZX,BVC,CA.NL.DSS,CA.SK.FCAA","QQQQQQQQQRRCGHDKLKSLS"
```

The code which I am trying to write is as below :

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

import csv

OUT_FILE = '/proj/ctc/temp/sanjay/REC-754/2017-05-29_IR_Position_Report_US_US_2017-05-30_out.csv'
IN_FILE = '/proj/ctc/temp/sanjay/REC-754/2017-05-29_IR_Position_Report_US_US_2017-05-30.csv'

f = open(IN_FILE, 'r')
o = open(OUT_FILE,'w')

with f:
 reader = csv.reader(f)
with o:
 writer = csv.writer(o)
 for row in reader:
    reportable_jurisdiction=row[68]
    if ',' in reportable_jurisdiction:
        row[68]=sorted(list(row[68].split(',')))
        print " reportable Jurisdiction with comma "+reportable_jurisdiction
    else:
        print "reportable Jurisdiction if single "+reportable_jurisdiction

        if(f.closed):
            f=open(IN_FILE,"r") 
        if(o.closed):
            o=open(OUT_FILE,"w")
    writer.writerow(row)
    print(row)
```

but when I am executing this python script I am getting below error:

```
$./Csvreader2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Csvreader2.py", line 15, in <module>
    for row in reader:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I got out of this issue and the issue was with indentation of the code
but I got the new issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Csvreader2.py", line 14, in <module>
    reportable_jurisdiction=row[68]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

in My CSV file there are more than 100 columns, but why getting this error?

Comment: Indent your code that uses `f` to not fall outside of the `with` block that keeps it open. You need to keep the file open until you are  done with reading from it, the `csv.reader()` doesn't take all data into memory, you need to keep the file open.

Comment: Thanks for your input.. code is indented in the same way. but again the problem remains same.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that the problem is with your indentation. It is wrong. You need to indent the second `with` statement to be at the same level as `reader = `, or combine the two `with` statements into one. Your first `with` statement *ends* and closes `f` at the moment.

Comment: indent tab or 4 spaces everything from `with o:`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters.. thanks for your responses .. yes Indentation was the problem.how ever I got another issue Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Csvreader2.py", line 14, in <module>
    reportable_jurisdiction=row[68]
IndexError: list index out of range
 but in my file there are more than 100 columns ?

Comment: @user2779202: apparently not *all* rows do.

Comment: All the rows are having more than 100 columns..

Answer (score 1):

You are using the files as context managers:

```
with f:
    # ...
with o:
    # ...
```

Once the `with` block ends (the indentation level of subsequent code is lower or equal to the `with` statement indentation), the file is *closed* and can't be read from anymore. This means that file `f` is closed the moment the `with o:` line is executed.

However, you need `f` to remain open so you can keep reading from it through the `csv.reader` object. Keep both files open at the same time, by putting all your code under **one** `with` statement:

```
with f, o:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(o)
    for row in reader:
        # ...
```